# How to block private numbers

Tags: call-screening

I am getting way to many calls from marketers these days. I have listed my number on no call list and they still keep calling. Most of the time I can't be bothered [to report everyone](https://complaints.tpsonline.org.uk/consumer).

**How to block callers from private numbers that are hiding their Id?**

Comment: Per their description both [Call Control - Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flexaspect.android.everycallcontrol) and  [Call Blocker Gold](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=blacknWhite.CallBlocker.Gold) should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android version 5.1.1 (Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge)
One way to do it is go to `Phone` (like you would make a call) then click on the `More` in top right of the screen and choose `Settings` then `Call Settings > Call rejection > Auto reject list` and select the "**Unknown**" option.

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: It's probably worth [edit]ing your answer to add your device details as these options may not available on all devices (e.g. it's not available on my Nexus 6P).

Comment: @bmdixon I have added Andriod version do you think phone model is relevant too?

Comment: Yes, I've used Nexus devices for years and none of them have had this so worth adding your phone make and model. If it apples to other devices then people can comment/edit to add other info.