# How do I block private numbers from calling me?

Tags: calls, call-screening, dialer-codes, motorola-moto-e4

Android 7 on a motorola E4. [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129694/how-to-block-private-numbers) does not work for me as I simply don't have that menu.

How do I block private numbers from calling my phone?

I'm not looking for a 3rd party application. I'm thinking there must be some way to do this on an android level, maybe with some [hidden code](https://www.xda-developers.com/codes-hidden-android/)?

The phone isn't rooted, ADB isn't an option since data over USB on the phone is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Motorola uses a vanilla Android experience (similar to Android One & Pixel) and it ships with the Google dialer and Google contacts app. As such, you will not find as many options in your phone as we see in Xiaomi or Huawei or Samsung phones. The call blocking option is also not present in the stock Android setup.

You will have to resort to a 3rd party app from the Play Store. I wouldn't recommend any as there are many call blocking apps and you should be free to evaluate them and choose the one to your liking.